# Assigning values according to set limits in R

Tags: r, while-loop, dataframe

I have a list of stores with some quantities of different articles in them and a warehouse with these articles - these are two separate data frames.

```
Article <- c('a','b','a','b','c','d')
forecast <- c( 1,5,80,10,100,1000)
StoreID <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4)
StoreData <- data.frame(StoreID, Article, Order)
```

Smth like this:

```
StoreData
StoreID Article forecast
1       a        1
1       b        5
2       a       80
2       b       10
3       c      100
4       d     1000
```

And the warehouse data:

```
Stock <- c(10,11,12,100)
WarehouseData <- data.frame(Article, Stock)

WarehouseData
Article Stock
a    10
b    11
c    12
d   100
```

My target is to have a purchase order column. The logic has to be following: for every row in the StoreData table I have to look at the Stock of the Article in the Warehouse and if it is enough - approve the fcst, if not - approve only the avaulable quantity. My problem is that while approving quantities the avaialble stock is reducing and I cannot find out how to take it into account.

The expected result looks like this:

```
StoreData
StoreID Article forecast PO
1       a        1        1
1       b        5        5
2       a       80        9
2       b       10        6
3       c      100       12
4       d     1000      100
```

Can anyone, please, tell how to get it right?

Comment: why is the `PO` of the  first observation of a = 1 (same as forecast) but the first observation of c and d same as `Stock` from `WarehouseData` ?

Comment: You require going down the store ID's sequentially? For example, if Store 1's forecast for an article uses up all the available stock then store 2's order will not be filled?

Comment: @Sotos that is exactly the point - I have to approve the forecast in this column if there is enough quantity in the Warehouse. If there is less stock I need to assign the available stock from the watehouse instead of the forecast

Comment: ah...ok, it makes sense

Comment: @NBATrends you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the loop below for example:

```
StoreData$PO <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(StoreData)) {
  query <- WarehouseData$Article == StoreData[i, "Article"]
  po <- ifelse(StoreData[i, "forecast"] > WarehouseData[query, 2], 
               WarehouseData[query, 2],
               StoreData[i, "forecast"])

  WarehouseData[query, 2] <- WarehouseData[query, 2] - po
  StoreData[i, "PO"] <- po
}

print(StoreData)
# StoreID Article forecast  PO
# 1       1       a        1   1
# 2       1       b        5   5
# 3       2       a       80   9
# 4       2       b       10   6
# 5       3       c      100  12
# 6       4       d     1000 100
```

This is another alternative based on the other solution using base R:

```
StoreData <- merge(StoreData, WarehouseData)
StoreData$PO <- do.call(c, lapply(split(StoreData, StoreData$Article), function(z) {
  ifelse(cumsum(z$forecast) <= z$Stock, z$forecast, 
         z$Stock - cumsum(z$forecast) + z$forecast) 
}))
```

And here is what I used to recreate your dataset, might help other answers:

```
StoreData <- read.table(text = "StoreID Article forecast
                        1       a        1
                        1       b        5
                        2       a       80
                        2       b       10
                        3       c      100
                        4       d     1000", header = T)


Article <- c('a','b','c','d')
Stock <- c(10,11,12,100)
WarehouseData <- data.frame(Article, Stock)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Now will try to figure out how it works :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(storeData, WarehouseData, by = "Article") %>% 
  group_by(Article) %>% 
  mutate(PO = ifelse(cumsum(forecast) <= Stock, forecast, 
                     Stock - cumsum(forecast) + forecast)) %>% ungroup

#Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
#
#  StoreID Article forecast Stock    PO
#    (int)  (fctr)    (int) (dbl) (dbl)
#1       1       a        1    10     1
#2       1       b        5    11     5
#3       2       a       80    10     9
#4       2       b       10    11     6
#5       3       c      100    12    12
#6       4       d     1000   100   100
```